# Plotting blends of colors over lists of lists in 3D

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

I have a list of lists containing spectral data, many thousands of points long.  Each sublist contains 13 parts, and I need to plot them in 3D with a blend of RGB colors derived from the spectral data.  So no problem until I get to coloring the plots.  How can I use the list of 13 RGB triplets to create a blend to color each list plot?

Here are two datasets, one for a plot and one for the corresponding colors:

```
spectral = {{{48.76`, 63.49`, 72.76`, 76.78`, 78.02`, 78.96`, 79.73`, 
 80.41`, 81.21`, 81.83`, 82.39`, 83.03`, 83.56`, 84, 84.42`, 
 84.53`, 84.69`, 84.74`, 84.55`, 84.73`, 84.56`, 84.47`, 84.31`, 
 84.25`, 84.09`, 83.81`, 83.67`, 83.58`, 83.39`, 83.05`, 82.76`, 
 82.49`, 82.35`, 82.33`, 82.16`, 82.06`}, {42.08`, 57.42`, 67.24`,
  72.1`, 73.91`, 75.4`, 76.73`, 77.54`, 77.96`, 77.76`, 77.04`, 
 75.64`, 74.02`, 72.55`, 71.15`, 70.15`, 70.04`, 69.92`, 69.35`, 
 69.21`, 69.33`, 69.99`, 70.29`, 70.17`, 69.92`, 69.77`, 70.09`, 
 70.87`, 71.69`, 72.08`, 71.95`, 71.48`, 70.77`, 70.14`, 69.89`, 
 70.46`}, {42.03`, 56.78`, 66.37`, 70.92`, 72.63`, 74, 75.27`, 
 76.02`, 76.44`, 76.32`, 75.7`, 74.46`, 72.96`, 71.53`, 70.1`, 
 69.06`, 68.94`, 68.84`, 68.22`, 68.03`, 68.19`, 68.93`, 69.25`, 
 69.12`, 68.84`, 68.71`, 69.1`, 69.89`, 70.76`, 71.15`, 71.03`, 
 70.59`, 69.92`, 69.35`, 69.18`, 69.79`}, {39.03`, 53.63`, 63.5`, 
 68.37`, 70.26`, 71.8`, 73.19`, 73.93`, 74.24`, 73.92`, 72.91`, 
 71.04`, 68.78`, 66.59`, 64.33`, 62.75`, 62.43`, 62.19`, 61.25`, 
 60.78`, 61.04`, 62.1`, 62.66`, 62.45`, 62.06`, 61.91`, 62.52`, 
 63.73`, 65.08`, 65.81`, 65.78`, 65.28`, 64.36`, 63.57`, 63.44`, 
 64.42`}, {31.22`, 46.21`, 57.41`, 63.54`, 66.14`, 68.43`, 70.44`,
  71.39`, 71.38`, 70.37`, 68.2`, 64.36`, 59.76`, 55.23`, 50.36`, 
 46.94`, 45.98`, 45.24`, 43.14`, 41.64`, 42.14`, 44.33`, 45.51`, 
 45.06`, 44.19`, 44.02`, 45.32`, 47.88`, 50.81`, 52.62`, 52.78`, 
 52.06`, 50.5`, 49.01`, 49.26`, 51.58`}, {26.44`, 40.79`, 52.46`, 
 59, 61.93`, 64.58`, 66.88`, 67.92`, 67.76`, 66.38`, 63.6`, 
 58.72`, 52.92`, 47.21`, 41.06`, 36.78`, 35.48`, 34.49`, 31.86`, 
 29.83`, 30.43`, 33.14`, 34.6`, 34.03`, 32.93`, 32.74`, 34.34`, 
 37.51`, 41.2`, 43.52`, 43.79`, 42.96`, 41.05`, 39.21`, 39.61`, 
 42.46`}, {22.15`, 36.49`, 49.02`, 56.44`, 59.88`, 62.99`, 65.73`,
  66.93`, 66.45`, 64.57`, 60.92`, 54.74`, 47.62`, 40.78`, 33.58`, 
 28.71`, 27.21`, 26.08`, 23.15`, 20.89`, 21.54`, 24.47`, 26.08`, 
 25.45`, 24.24`, 24.08`, 25.86`, 29.41`, 33.6`, 36.35`, 36.72`, 
 35.8`, 33.66`, 31.63`, 32.2`, 35.6`}, {20.01`, 33.94`, 46.53`, 
 54.05`, 57.59`, 60.8`, 63.56`, 64.79`, 64.3`, 62.28`, 58.44`, 
 51.89`, 44.29`, 36.94`, 29.19`, 23.96`, 22.35`, 21.13`, 18.05`, 
 15.69`, 16.37`, 19.42`, 21.11`, 20.41`, 19.13`, 18.95`, 20.8`, 
 24.56`, 29.03`, 31.97`, 32.39`, 31.44`, 29.18`, 27.01`, 27.62`, 
 31.29`}, {18.84`, 32.74`, 45.29`, 52.81`, 56.47`, 59.72`, 62.63`,
  63.89`, 63.37`, 61.31`, 57.38`, 50.67`, 42.9`, 35.39`, 27.53`, 
 22.23`, 20.58`, 19.35`, 16.25`, 13.85`, 14.51`, 17.54`, 19.22`, 
 18.53`, 17.25`, 17.06`, 18.91`, 22.67`, 27.19`, 30.17`, 30.61`, 
 29.66`, 27.37`, 25.16`, 25.81`, 29.51`}, {18.4`, 32.15`, 45.16`, 
 53.05`, 56.88`, 60.39`, 63.55`, 64.83`, 64.16`, 61.86`, 57.5`, 
 50.25`, 42.03`, 34.26`, 26.29`, 21.02`, 19.39`, 18.18`, 15.16`, 
 12.84`, 13.47`, 16.4`, 18, 17.31`, 16.04`, 15.85`, 17.63`, 
 21.31`, 25.79`, 28.79`, 29.22`, 28.25`, 25.92`, 23.72`, 24.38`, 
 28.08`}, {17.83`, 31.87`, 44.91`, 53, 56.88`, 60.41`, 63.52`, 
 64.85`, 64.22`, 61.88`, 57.5`, 50.17`, 41.77`, 33.79`, 25.52`, 
 20.04`, 18.35`, 17.08`, 13.94`, 11.54`, 12.2`, 15.23`, 16.93`, 
 16.21`, 14.92`, 14.73`, 16.6`, 20.44`, 25.11`, 28.25`, 28.72`, 
 27.72`, 25.33`, 23.07`, 23.77`, 27.65`}, {17.54`, 31.72`, 45.01`,
  53.08`, 57, 60.61`, 63.78`, 65.09`, 64.41`, 62.05`, 57.6`, 
 50.13`, 41.53`, 33.28`, 24.72`, 19.04`, 17.29`, 15.99`, 12.78`, 
 10.36`, 11.05`, 14.16`, 15.9`, 15.16`, 13.82`, 13.64`, 15.58`, 
 19.54`, 24.4`, 27.63`, 28.12`, 27.11`, 24.64`, 22.28`, 23.06`, 
 27.08`}, {17.39`, 31.68`, 45.1`, 53.25`, 57.15`, 60.74`, 63.93`, 
 65.22`, 64.55`, 62.22`, 57.77`, 50.24`, 41.55`, 33.19`, 24.5`, 
 18.73`, 16.96`, 15.64`, 12.41`, 10, 10.71`, 13.83`, 15.58`, 
 14.83`, 13.47`, 13.31`, 15.26`, 19.27`, 24.16`, 27.44`, 27.9`, 
 26.86`, 24.37`, 22, 22.75`, 26.82`}}};  
color={{{0.73, 0.73, 0.7}, {0.63, 0.64, 0.68}, {0.62, 0.63, 0.67}, {0.57, 0.59, 0.66}, {0.44, 0.48, 0.65}, {0.36, 0.41, 0.63}, {0.3, 0.35,0.62}, {0.26, 0.32, 0.61}, 
{0.25, 0.31, 0.6}, {0.24, 0.3,0.61}, {0.23, 0.29, 0.61}, {0.22, 0.28, 0.61}, {0.22, 0.28, 0.61}}};
```

Using ListPlot3D for the plots, How can I plot these colors as blends over ListPlot3d?

Comment: Is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gmOsl.png) what you were expecting?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this.  Could you please try to give an example or describe the output in a different way?

Comment: @rm-rf Almost!  It appears the colors need rotating on the plot by 90 degrees, but yes this is very close!!  Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Wizard rm-rf has a close example that will help show what I'm attempting to do.  thanks!

Comment: Okay, I'll let rm -rf answer this one then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Blend` to blend the colors and input the appropriate coordinate to the `ColorFunction` to get the coloring you desire.

```
With[{cf = Blend[RGBColor @@@ First@color, #] &},
    ListPlot3D[spectral, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, cf[y]]]]
```

For each of `x`, `y` and `z` as the input argument to `cf`, the following are the outputs:

[image]

Comment: sweet solution, thanks very much!

Comment: How can this be extended using Table to apply over multiple chunks for the list?

Comment: @RHall I don't understand what you mean by multiple chunks

Comment: this data is from one of the sublists for a multi thousand list of lists.  How can I map this solution over a list of lists? Thanks

Comment: @RHall Are all those lists to be plotted in the same plot? If you you could try plotting separately and using `Show` to combine them...

Comment: The list contains a few thousand data sets to be plotted individually. I am using a grid function to display all of the plots, but need to apply your solution to all of the datasets in these lists.

Comment: @RHall Then perhaps you could map `With[{cf = Blend[RGBColor @@@ First@color, #] &},
    ListPlot3D[#, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, cf[y]]]]&` onto each sublist?

Comment: Can we move to chat?